# Euclidian division of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic

I have to find the remainder of the division of $X^n$ by $X^2-6X-16$ for all positive integer $n$. I know how to do a euclidian division with polynomials but I am confused with the $n$ since I don't know if $n>2$ or not. How do I do such a division?

Comment: Closely related to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602623/how-do-i-divide-a-polynomial-of-a-very-high-degree-by-a-polynomial-of-degree-2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**

Write
$$X^n=(X^2-6X-16)Q(X)+aX+b\quad(*)$$
Replace $X$ in $(*)$ by the roots $-2$ and $8$ of $X^2-6X-16$ and solve the two equations of the unknowns $a$ and $b$.

**Edit**
We find
$$-2a+b=(-2)^n\quad;\quad 8a+b=8^n$$
hence
$$a=\frac{8^n-(-2)^n}{10}\quad;\quad b=\frac{8^n+4(-2)^n}{5}$$

Comment: Using you method, I found $a=(2^n+8^n)/10$ and $b=(8^n-4.2^n)/5$. Is that right?

Comment: @moray95 I edited my answer.

Comment: +1. Sami, regarding to your new avatar, I thin everything can be solved easily, even mathematical ones, by saying that holly words. و قال ارکبوا فیها بسم الله مجراها و مرساها